# Shift Redis keys

Tags: redis, redis-py

In my Redis DB, I've got a list of keys saved in a format of `prefix:<index>`, so the sample DB looks like this:

```
prefix:0 = "lorem"
prefix:1 = "ipsum"
prefix:2 = "dolor"
prefix:3 = "sit"
```

The problem is when I try to delete `prefix:1`, because I need the `ipsum` gone for whatever reason, I'm left with a gap between indexes – the DB being like this:

```
prefix:0 = "lorem"
prefix:2 = "dolor"
prefix:3 = "sit"
```

And I need the DB to be like this:

```
prefix:0 = "lorem"
prefix:1 = "dolor"
prefix:2 = "sit"
```

How do I shift the indexes of keys to fill the gap (shifting `prefix:2` to `prefix:1` and `prefix:3` to `prefix:2`) in Python with the `redis-py` library? All I can think of is looping through all keys with index greater than deleted index and rename them, but I'd prefer a bulk solution, if there's any.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure of what you are trying to solve here exactly by using **redis** and shifting keys inside of it. You could just delete `prefix:3` rather than deleting `prefix:1` and then shifting the remaining keys. I am not sure what I'm missing, please do add more clarity to your question.

```
Operation :  DELETE `prefix:1` and SHIFT <=> DELETE `prefix:3`
Input     : `prefix:0` `prefix:1` `prefix:2` `prefix:3`
Output    : `prefix:0` `prefix:1` `prefix:2`
```

Comment: Just edited my question. Hope I clarified. The thing is, that I need to conserve the values of the keys and just rename them.

Comment: Will it be okay to use different data types like Redis lists? Will you know the value to delete as in `ipsum` or the key as in `prefix:1` or both?

Comment: All of them are going to be the same type - string, and I will in fact know both the key and value in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a really inefficient approach to be managing manually - any reason why you wouldn't use a Redis list (needing separate time to live on each entry would be one reason not to).  If you really do want to bubble up the key names to fill a gap in your sequence created by deleting one key, check out the `RENAME` command: https://redis.io/commands/rename/